# ComputerInfo.OSFullName

Tags: c#

Почему-то происходит какой-то сбой, программа просто закрывается без ошибки, когда пытаюсь получить OSFullName, но при получении OSVersion все отлично, что может быть? `new ComputerInfo().OSFullName;`

Comment: не смог воспроизвести ошибку; возможно, вызывающему коду не хватает прав, либо на компьютере не установлен инструментарий управления Windows (WMI) -- скорее всего первое, оберни в `try catch`, посмотри описание исключения;

`OSFullName` вызывает `SecurityException` не просто так :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо этого способа использовал такой код:

```
public static string OSName()
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
    foreach (ManagementObject os in searcher.Get())
    {
        result = os["Caption"].ToString();
        break;
    }
    return result;
}
```